# C# console program - stop STDIN from going to STDOUT

Tags: c#, .net-2.0, console, stdout, stdin

I'm writing a simple console app in C#, .NET 2.0.  It starts new threads using a threading timer, while it interprets commands on the main thread.

I currently take three commands:
P - Pause
C - Continue
Q - Quit

This functionality works quite well, but unfortunately when I type P, C, or Q (or any other character for that matter), the character goes to STDOUT.  Is there a way I can stop this programatically?  Also it'd be useful to know if I could disable and re-enable STDIN -> STDOUT.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: C# doesn't refer to it as STDIN and STDOUT.

Comment: I don't think you're asking the right question.  Are you upset that whenever you press a key it's echo'd?  Console.Read() is used to read in characters, and unless you tell it otherwise, it'll be echo'd into STDOUT (which is normal).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Sounds like you are using

```
Console.ReadKey();
```

Which clearly states in the documentation that it prints to the screen and if you don't want to output to the screen you should use the overloaded version

```
Console.ReadKey(true);
```

Which does not output.